# Inserting images to a table queried from database

Tags: python, mysql, report, reportlab

I am trying to create a report containing a table with Reportlab. The information is being queried from a MySQL table which also holds the url to the image I want to insert in the table in the pdf.

I can easily create the table in the pdf with the information needed. I do however have issues getting the picture inserted in the same row in the pdf as the values being queried. Any suggestions on this?

```
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.platypus import Image, Paragraph, SimpleDocTemplate, Table
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
import MySQLdb

doc = SimpleDocTemplate("Students.pdf")
elements = []
styleSheet = getSampleStyleSheet()

# Connect to db
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="test", passwd="test", db="test")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT id, FirstName, LastName, image FROM students');
rows = cursor.fetchall()

data = []
data.append(['Id', 'FirstName', 'LastName, 'Image'])

# loop through database select and a to list
for row in rows:
    data.append(row)

t=Table(data,style=[
    ('GRID',(0,0),(-1,-1),0.5,colors.black),
    ('ALIGN',(0,0),(-1,-1),'CENTER'),
])

elements.append(t)

# write the document to disk
doc.build(elements)

conn.close()
```

[All in all this is what i am aiming at, in the pdf:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/batzP.png)

Comment: If you already have the URL why do you need to insert the picture a wel??

Comment: I would like the picture to be included in the table in the report like
Id, FirstName, LastName, <Picture of student>. By report i mean PDF

Comment: so why don't you edit your table to make it clear where you are talking about the table on the database and where you are talking about the table on the report.

Comment: e4c5 I read my post again and could see what you mean. I have added more information to distinguish between table in the pdf and in the database.

Comment: Why are making the Table inside the loop? Shouldn't you be only building the list and then passing that to Table outside the loop

Comment: It was the formatting when copying the code. I have corrected it. The table should be build outside the loop. you are sharp :)